# Using karate-config parameters in a java file

Tags: karate

Is there a possibility in karate to reuse parameters from karat-config.js in java file ( Initialising values using constructor)

Comment: can you provide more details of how would you want to reuse a variable in config, like any sample code snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since anything returned from `karate-config.js` is available any time in any-scenario, just instantiate the Java class and pass whatever you need in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a /resources/properties.yml that you import into the karate-config.js, and the values in the yml could be directly accessible in Java as well.